# Как отслеживать нажатие правой кнопки мыши в QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget, eventfilter, qlistwidgetitem

Подскажите пожалуйста, как привязать функцию к щелчку правой кнопке мыши по `QListWidgetItem`?

Нашел в документации только `itemClicked` и `itemDoubleClicked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете устанавливает фильтр событий на объект `list_widget`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.list_widget.installEventFilter(self)
        
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("add")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.add_item)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.list_widget, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 1, 0)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.list_widget and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu: 
            item = self.list_widget.currentItem()
            if item:
                text = item.text()
                print(f'clicked item text: {text}')
       
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def add_item(self):
        num = self.list_widget.count()
        self.list_widget.addItem(f"item {num}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: eventFilter это переопределение метода в Widget?

Comment: @СашаЯночкин почитайте пожалуйста https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter . Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour